# Access specific named node in KML file using VBS

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic, kml

I am extracting a postcode and coordinates out of a KML file (to build a huge Javascript array) however I am having trouble targeting the value in the  node named 'POA_2006'  I am running this in a .vbs file.  I can do this with a .singleNode or .namedItem normally with XML files but can not get either of these to work with a KML file that look like this (I have no control over the KML file.  Its a massive 180mb file containing all the coordinate shapes for all postcodes in Australia):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="postcode" id="postcode">
<SimpleField name="STATE_2006" type="string"></SimpleField>
<SimpleField name="POA_2006" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>postcode</name>
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#postcode">
    <SimpleData name="STATE_2006">1</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="POA_2006">2000</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>151.20118275199999,-33.873293252 ,-33.851193004 151.19797801600001</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

Here is the code that I am forced to use which is working however I do not like the fact I ave to do this 'if (i mod 1.5) = 1 then' to always ignore the first  node to make sure it skips to the second  node which contains my postcode

```
    function readKLMFileAndWriteToFile(toFileName, fromFileName)
        Dim objxml, fso, filetxt, getname, path 
        Set objxml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        objxml.async = False
        objxml.load (fromFileName)
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        Set filetxt = fso.CreateTextFile(toFileName, True) 
        path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(toFileName) 
        getname = fso.GetFileName(path) 
        writeLog "A file called " & getname & " was created"    

        Dim SimpleData, SimpleDataLen, coords,coordsLen,i, ctr, i2
        set SimpleData = objxml.getElementsByTagName("SimpleData")
        SimpleDataLen  = SimpleData.length-1
        set coords     = objxml.getElementsByTagName("coordinates")
        coordsLen      = coords.length-1
        ctr = 0
        for i = 0 to SimpleDataLen
              'filetxt.write i & " mod = " & i mod 1.5 & "]" & vbcrlf
              'why can I not target the named 'POA_2006' node! Use this workaround to only show every second SimpleData node 
              if (i mod 1.5) = 1 then
                  filetxt.write "var postcode_" & SimpleData.item(i).Text & " = ["
                  filetxt.write replace(coords.item(ctr).Text, " ", ",") & "];" & vbcrlf 
                  ctr = ctr+1
              end if
        next
        filetxt.Close 
    end function
```

Any ideas how I can target the  node directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target it through an [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.85).aspx) selection query. At the start, choose the selection language

```vb
' put this in before .load()
objxml.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

Then you may also need to add the namespace to your `SelectionNamespaces` property of the XML document:

```vb
objxml.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:k=""http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"""
```

You need to give it name - here I used `k`. Now you can directly query the node in question:

```
set SimpleData = objxml.SelectSingleNode("//k:SimpleData[@name='POA_2006']")
```

The [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method returns a single object not a collection, so you can access the node's context just with `SimpleData.text`.

```vb
filetxt.write "var postcode_" & SimpleData.Text & " = ["
```

Comment: HI there.  I can loop throught after setting this Set SimpleData = objxml.selectNodes("/") but this set SimpleData = objxml.SelectSingleNode("//k:SimpleData[@name='POA_2006']") does not give me any error however I can not print out the values.  How are you printing this SimpleData(0).text ?

Comment: Thank you for you time.  for the record I was wrong doing this SimpleData(0).text its has to be simpleData.text